# Bootchart and how to optimize boot time

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader, bootchart

I have spent some time researching how to decrease my boot time. I made several changes to my grub boot parameters.  However I could really use some help to understanding what else I could do. I spent some time looking at other treads on this site about this topic and make some tweaks they suggested but it made it worse. [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bHUy.png) is the direct link for my bootchart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fifteen seconds?  **15secs?  That is really impressive!**

And you *actually* want to *optimise that*??? **:-O**

I would say: [take a system back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) *now* (You're *definitely* user type 4!) and don't touch anything!!!  (except maybe remove `bootchart` as that takes time as well)

Your boot is faster then 99.75% of all users on this site and faster then 99.999% of all user on this planet!

[Congratulations!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23ZG6HJVKuQ)

Comment: It just seems like it could be faster... I have seen em down in the 5s range. What is a user type 4? lol

Comment: The boot chart and the user experience are a different thing.  Could you time your boot with a stopwatch?  (don't count the BIOS screen: start counting when the BIOS disappears and stop when the User log-in shows.)  The system *continues booting while you're still entering your password*, so that should be taken out of the picture and if you count it like that, it's pretty fast!  Mine is 19 seconds when ntpdate gets run and that means: everything I need including Unity & network are completely ready.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CMnnZlUXLY) is a you-tube video of my computer going from on and restarting in under 24 seconds so I feel the boot chart is pretty accurate actually.  This includes the time for my desktop to show and me being able to move the mouse and do whatever I like. It isn't sluggish when it boots or anything. There is no"post processing" taking place.

Comment: That's a full restart!  Have you looked around on Macs and Windows machines?  Even with SSDs?  Pretty impressive...  I'm going to time mine now: 40 seconds...  Including BIOS, including checking for updates (there were none).  I'm going to update my answer!